# .htaccess Permalink redirect

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'd like to redirect my Wordpress posts from /%title/ to %year/%month/%title/.

Since WP automatically redirects the pages when you do a new permalink structure, I'd like to have the redirect in my .htaccess file anyway so that Google is aware of the change.

This is what I have in my .htaccess file, so I'd just liket to confirm this is the correct structure:

`RedirectMatch 301 http://url-example.com/$3 ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)$`

Let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the dynamic nature of the WordPress URLs, I do not believe you will have much luck doing this in a single rule.

You could explicitly list these in `.htaccess`. However, it's likely WordPress is handling these redirects correctly for Google (i.e. 301).

Use Firebug or HTTP Live Headers to verify.

Comment: I was wondering about that. So, the structure of RedirectMatch is correct, though?

Comment: Your pattern is correct, but I don't believe you can use a back reference in this way. This is a *cart before the horse* issue. That is you can't verify a new URL exists based on a old URL. That's the whole point of the rewrite. As such, I don't think .htaccess is going to help. Check the current redirect built into WordPress. It's possible it is using a proper 301 redirect.